# Animate Width Of a Frame Starting From Right To Left In Vb6

Tags: vb6

I'm showing some stock details to the user when a particular text box is lost focus, and because of less space on form i,m using a frame.i want to increase the width of the frame on which the stock labels are placed, Now i want it to increase starting from right to left with time stamp. Because the frame is placed on right side it has to start increasing width from right. i couldn't find any property on code snippet to do so..i any one has any idea, please assist me with that

i have used the normal width increase

```
If FrameYarnDtl.Width = 15 Then
    FrameYarnDtl.Width = 2100
ElseIf FrameYarnDtl.Width = 2100 Then
    FrameYarnDtl.Width = 4200
ElseIf FrameYarnDtl.Width = 4200 Then
    FrameYarnDtl.Width = 6300
End If
If FrameYarnDtl.Width = 6300 Then
    Timer1.Enabled = False
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's the New Year...
Hint: Reduce `FrameYarnDtl.Left` as `FrameYarnDtl.Width` increases.

Comment: Ooops! Happy New Year

Answer (score 0):

John Eason already fixed your problem, but if you wanted a working snippet here is one:

**EDIT**: you don't need to add any controls to the form just copy and paste the snippet.

```vb
Option Explicit

'*****************************************************************
'Author: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4938616/david
'Source: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53993968/4938616
'*****************************************************************

Private WithEvents tmrAnim As Timer
Private fraContainer As Frame
Private WithEvents btnStart As CommandButton

Private Sub btnStart_Click()
    Static dir_switch As Boolean

    'runs animation
    Call runAnim(dir_switch)

    'toggles the direction of the animation
    dir_switch = Not dir_switch
End Sub

'Call this function from wherever you need to trigger the animation
Private Sub runAnim(ByVal runBackwards As Boolean)
    Call timerCallback(-1, runBackwards)
    tmrAnim.Enabled = True
End Sub

'timer event that updates the key frames
Private Sub tmrAnim_Timer()
    Static key As Long

    'function returns true when the it's done with the animation
    'it is provided with a keyframe
    If timerCallback(key) Then
        key = 0
        tmrAnim.Enabled = False
    End If

    'keyframe update
    key = key + 1
End Sub

'this function is called from the timer and does the actual animation
Private Function timerCallback(ByRef key As Long, Optional ByRef runBack As Boolean = False) As Boolean
    Static backwardAnim As Boolean 'determines the direction the animation should occur

    'When key is negative this function is being called to set up its forwardAnim variable.
    'This is not a clean solution, it's just a quick workaround
    If key < 0 Then
        backwardAnim = runBack
        Exit Function
    End If

    'variables that keep track of animation flow
    Dim kLeft As Long, kWidth As Long
    'constants that store the ranges for the animation
    'these could be global, but I don't like global variables
    Const INI_LEFT As Long = 10, END_LEFT As Long = 170
    Const INI_WIDTH As Long = 320, END_WIDTH As Long = 160

    'determines the last key frame in the animation (inclusive)
    Const MAX_KEY As Long = 8

    Dim progress As Single

    'determines the direction of the animation progress
    If Not backwardAnim Then
        progress = key / MAX_KEY
    Else
        progress = (MAX_KEY - key) / MAX_KEY
    End If

    'This is just a linear function of the form "c = a - (a - b) * n"
    'where a and b are two arbitrary points, and c is any point in between
    'a and b when 0 <= n < 1
    fraContainer.Left = INI_LEFT - (INI_LEFT - END_LEFT) * progress
    fraContainer.Width = INI_WIDTH - (INI_WIDTH - END_WIDTH) * progress

    'returns value to caller (timer) to determine when to stop
    timerCallback = key = MAX_KEY
End Function

'Inititalizes the controls added programmatically
'it's here to the bottom because it's not relevant for the purposes of this example
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set tmrAnim = Me.Controls.Add("VB.Timer", "tmrAnim", Me)
    Set fraContainer = Me.Controls.Add("VB.Frame", "fraContainer", Me)
    Set btnStart = Me.Controls.Add("VB.CommandButton", "btnStart", fraContainer)

    Me.ScaleMode = vbTwips
    Me.Width = (Me.Width - Me.ScaleWidth) + 340 * VB.Screen.TwipsPerPixelX
    Me.Height = (Me.Height - Me.ScaleHeight) + 260 * VB.Screen.TwipsPerPixelY
    Me.ScaleMode = vbPixels

    'Initialize timer object properties
    With tmrAnim
        .Interval = 16 'cycles ~ every 25 milliseconds
        .Enabled = False
    End With

    'Initialize frame object properties
    With fraContainer
        .Caption = "Placeholder text"
        .Move 10, 10, 320, 240
        .Visible = True
    End With

    'Initialize CommandButton object properties
    With btnStart
        .Default = True
        .Caption = "Start Animation"

        'This button's parent is a frame and frames don't inherit or can change their scale mode.
        'Default are Twips which are 8 times bigger than pixels
        .Move 10 * VB.Screen.TwipsPerPixelX, 20 * VB.Screen.TwipsPerPixelX, 120 * VB.Screen.TwipsPerPixelX, 20 * VB.Screen.TwipsPerPixelX

        .Visible = True
    End With
End Sub
```

- The timer that generates keyframes
- Within the timer event I call `timerCallback` that receives a keyframe and manages the animation
- Constants within `timerCallback` control the beginning and ending of the animation as well as how many keyframes there is going to be
- The timer is enabled by a function called `runAnim`
- `runAnim` can be called from anywhere you wish to enable the animation.